# Django REST framework - hyperlink text not showing in api view

Tags: django, rest, hyperlink

In HyperlinkedRelatedField.to_representation(), it returns a Hyperlink(url, name) where name is the string representation of the object. Instead, the html shows:

```
<a href="http://example.com/api/contacts/123">http://example.com/api/contacts/123</a>
```

for this model listing (simplified):

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    when = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.when)
```

According to the documentation for Hyperlink:

```
A string like object that additionally has an associated name. 
We use this for hyperlinked URLs that may render as a named 
link in some contexts, or render as a plain URL in others
```

Why is the hyperlink not showing the string representation for 'Contact', but instead showing only the url? Is this a bug in the rest framework (I am using version 3.4)? Can someone point me to the location to the rendering code so I can see for myself what is happening?